# Cassandra Table Design: one column VS multi composite columns

Tags: cassandra, database-schema

Assume we will desgin a table to store user-like relationship in Cassandra, there are two approaches: one is to use multi columns for each fields, the other is to save all data as JSON format in a single column. which one is better?

## 1

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (  
  user_id text,  
  like_user_id text,  
  source text,  
  rate text,  
  create_time timestamp,  
  update_time timestamp,  
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, like_user_id)  
);
```

## 2

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (  
    user_id text,  
    like_user_id text,  
    json_data text,  
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, like_user_id)  
);
```

Comment: How do you query it? Will you always need all the data? Most likely either will work but (1) is more structured and provides more options to allow C* to do things like aggregations. (2) _may_ actually be more space efficient in some situations.

Comment: Normally query it by primary key, only part of row is required for each query